# Can you set an access key of an S3 object?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded three files to S3. `a.zip, b.zip, c.zip`

I would like to allow certain people to download some of those files over HTTP by clicking a link in their browser. Is it possible to have key associated with each file that isn't guessable (like the filename) so I can share the URL with the key and they won't be able to download the other files by substituting the filename:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/a.zip?key=DIFFICULT_SECRET1
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/b.zip?key=DIFFICULT_SECRET2
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/c.zip?key=DIFFICULT_SECRET3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with query string authentication via signed URLs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Once you generate a signed url for one object, it only ever works on that single object, and is, for all practical purposes, impossible to reverse engineer or modify in order to access any other object.  Signed URLs also have a finite expiration time, which you can set when you sign them.

Comment: This looks good, do any specific permissions need to be set on the bucket or do signed URL take priority?

Comment: The IAM account associated with the access-key-id needs permission to retrieve the object.  As long as there is no policy that would explicitly deny the action, the request is authenticated and access to the object will be granted based on the permissions of the IAM user.